# Assign ListAdapter to ListView in layout

Tags: android, listview

My main activity has a layout containing a ListView and several other items. I'd like to assign a ListAdapter to it. I followed the tutorials shown here: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html

How can I let the adapter know that my activity's layout has a ListView in it, and assign it to it? When I try to run the app as-is it crashes with a runtime exception stating that my layout needs to have the default Android listview in it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your activity is inherited from `ListActivity`, you don't have to manually let the adapter know the `ListView`.

But in order to do this, `ListView` in your activity should look like this

```
<ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
```

because [documentation says](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html)

> your own view MUST contain a ListView object with the id "@android:id/list" (or list if it's in code)

Comment: Now I feel foolish. Thanks for a simple, effective answer!

Answer (score 0):

> When I try to run the app as-is it crashes with a runtime exception stating that my layout needs to have the default Android listview in it.

It sounds like you're using a ListActivity and calling `setContentView()`.  In the layout that you pass to `setContentView()` you *must* have a ListView with the following attribute:

```
<ListView 
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    ... />
```

Then bind your Adapter to the ListView with `setListAdapter()`.